# Is Java Stream connected to the Database?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

```
public List<Post> getPosts(String city) {
    // if City parameter is presented(When searched by an user)
    if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(city)) {
        return postRepository.findAllByCityOrderByIdDesc(city).stream().map(obj -> {
            obj.getUser().setPassword("");
            return obj;
        }).collect((Collectors.toList()));
    } else {
        return postRepository.findAllByOrderByIdDesc().stream().map(obj -> {
            obj.getUser().setPassword("");
            return obj;
        }).collect((Collectors.toList()));
    }
}
```

I tried to change object values with the stream map function after fetching data from the DB, and the values in the DB changed too.

are they two connected?

Comment: No, stream map should not change the data in db

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you're using a stream to operate on the values in the list is entirely irrelevant:

- JPA is a "magic" technology that specifically provides the feature of automatically persisting changes that you make to JPA entity objects.
- The `stream()` just takes an existing collection of objects and operates on them.
- You are modifying the objects in `map`, which is not recommended in general. You could `detach` the users from the `EntityManager`, but...
- you should be mapping these to DTOs rather than presenting the entity objects to your top-level API layer, and
- when you have chunks like this that need to be isolated, you should consider separating your database model so that the "public profile" part of the user and the authentication part aren't grouped together.